# I don't know what my countertop is made of

Tags: kitchens

We live in a house that was built in the  70s. We want to paint the countertops but we have no idea what the material is! Any ideas? Suggestions for painting ?[image]

Comment: It looks like a standard laminate, but it could be many other materials getting a clear infocus photo of scratches or any imperfections would be helpful.

Comment: I would suggest **not** painting a counter top. It will last minutes, if you're lucky.

Comment: Not to mention the risk of getting paint chips in food.

Comment: Instead of paint, think about recovering with new laminate cover.

Comment: use a purposeful epoxy counter refinisher like stone coat or giani; worth the money if you can follow directions very carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Suggestions for painting: **DON'T!** it's a terrible idea and won't last. Just going to be a waste of time and money and then you'll have to replace the countertop anyway.

Your picture is unclear, but "built in the 1970's" makes the odds that it's Formica® laminate (gray linen pattern?) over plywood with (apparently) copper edging pretty good.

Comment: As a counterpoint to the DON'T (which I, by the way would generally tend to personally agree with), I used to own a house where the previous occupant had the laminate countertops professionally repainted before they sold the house to a neutral beige color.  It held up quite well for the 8+ years we lived there with young kids, so if done right (and professionally with the proper prep and paint materials) it may work, at least for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of paint, think about recovering with new laminate cover.

It looks like it is nice and flat without any bends, so it should be easy to do.

They sell covers to redo countertops, and should come in different designs/colours.  Would be more durable than paint.

Have not done it myself, but it looks like it only takes a good cleaning of the old surface, using contact cement, and carefully laying down the new surface.